# Error while parsing JSON babel failure

Tags: reactjs, gulp, babeljs

When I run gulp I get error while parsing JSON:

```
Syntax Error 'C:\Path\main.js' Error while parsing JSON
at: 98
text: '{\r\n   "development":
```

"text" is truncated in the command line.  I tried piping the output to a file and that failed because the error did not showup in the file:

Powershell cmd

`gulp | Out-File C:\temp.txt -width 120`

package.json

```
{
  "name": "helloreact",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.5.1",
    "babel-plugin-react-transform": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "babelify": "^7.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.5",
    "flux": "^2.0.3",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-connect": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-eslint": "^1.1.1",
    "gulp-open": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0",
    "jquery": "^2.1.4",
    "jquery-csv": "^0.8.1",
    "lodash": "^4.0.1",
    "object-assign": "^4.0.1",
    "react": "^0.13.3",
    "react-router": "^0.13.3",
    "react-tools": "^0.10.0",
    "react-transform": "0.0.3",
    "reactify": "^1.1.1",
    "redbox-react": "^1.2.2",
    "toastr": "^2.1.0",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": ["react-transform"],
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My gulp task uses `babelify`

```
gulp.task('js', function(){
  browserify(config.paths.mainJs,  { debug: true })
      .transform(babel, {presets: ["react"]})
      .transform(reactify)
      .bundle()
      .on('error', console.error.bind(console))
      .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
      .pipe(sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true }))
      .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))//TODO: not sure if this syntax is correct
      .pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.dist + '/scripts'))
      .pipe(connect.reload())
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try removing the extra comma in your `bablerc`

```
{
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": ["react-transform"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You are on the right track.  It is a problem with babelrc.  Problem is that when I change my babelrc file I get an error saying that jQuery cannot be found.  This only happens if I build with babel.

Comment: I modified the .babelrc file to be `{ "presets": ["react"] }` and now it works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

my situation is : react + redux project . my origin .babelrc content is

```js
{
  "presets" : ["es2015","react"]
}
```

i remove "es2015" from presets and webpack worked

Answer (score 0):

Changing it to

```js
{ "presets": ["@babel/env"] }
```

in `.babelrc` file, fixed it for me.